# From sql query to Pandas (pd.NamedAgg() )

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I would like to transform this query with a pandas function, but I have problems with variables constructed from other variables, e.g. var1. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the query:

```
select
AVG(VAR_1),
AVG(VAR2+ VAR3) AS X,
1 - (SUM(VAR1)/SUM(VAR2)) AS Y,
AVG((VAR1) / ((VAR2/ 1.22) - VAR3)) AS Z
FROM data
group by id
```

And this is my pandas function incomplete:

```
df = input.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False) \
                    .agg(VAR1 = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'VAR1', aggfunc='mean'),
                         X =  pd.NamedAgg(),
                         Y  = pd.NamedAgg(),
                         Z = pd.NamedAgg()
                    )
```

How do I complete this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pandasql`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.DataFrame('Define your fataframe')

q1 = """ <PLACE YOUR SQL QUERY HERE> """

print(ps.sqldf(q1, locals())) # or globals
```

Comment: I try pandasql but there isn't standard deviation function.....

Comment: Place the sql query in "q1"